# Display entries by current entry author?

Tags: loop, author

I have a blog section on my site and would like a "More posts by this author" list. How would I go about this, the logic is clear but the syntax to write for it is not forthcoming.

Answer (score 5):

In order to display all other entries by an author except the current one, you will need to perform another step — either by filtering out the current entry from the query or adding a conditional.

```
{% set authorId = entry.author.id %}
{% set allEntryIds = craft.entries.section('blog').authorId(authorId).limit(null).ids() %}
{% set otherEntryIds = allEntryIds|without(entry.id) %}
{% set otherEntries = craft.entries.section('blog').id(otherEntryIds) %}

<ul>
    {% for entry in otherEntries %}
        <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

or

```
{% set authorId = entry.author.id %}
{% set authorEntries = craft.entries.section('blog').authorId(authorId).limit(null) %}
<ul>
    {% for authorEntry in authorEntries %}
        {% if not authorEntry.id == entry.id %}
            <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get entries by an author like this:

```
{% set authorPosts = craft.entries.section('posts').authorId(entry.authorId) %}
```

I think this returns an `ElementCriteriaModel` so you could do things like `.first()` `.limit(1)` etc but you can use it in a twig loop as is.